# jQuery easing Bounce animation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add a bounce effect to my animation but am having trouble doing so. I have been following the [jQuery API animate() page](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) but I keep failing. I am trying to create an effect where my object slides in from the top and bounces before settling into place.

```
$(this).animate( {
        "top": "+=100px"
    }, { 
        duration: '400',
        specialEasing: {
            width: 'linear',
            height: 'easeOutBounce'
        },
    }
);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not quite sure of what element specifically you're hoping to bounce, but try this:

```
$(this).animate({ "top" : "+=100px" }, 400, "easeOutBounce");
```

This requires the **jQuery Easing** plugin. More [info](https://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/), [github](https://github.com/gdsmith/jquery.easing/) or [CDN](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.4.1/jquery.easing.min.js).

**Demo:**

```js
$("#target").animate({ "top" : "+=100px" }, 400, "easeOutBounce");
```

```css
#target{ position:absolute; left:50px; top:50px; background:red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.4.1/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>

<div id='target'>Hellow World<div>
```

Comment: `this` refers to a div which contains a form. I tried your code but the console reports `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'easeOutBounce'`.

Comment: It's probably because you haven't included the easing plugin.  You can download it here: http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/

Comment: Glad to hear it!  I'd appreciate it if you marked the answer correct as well so it could help other people in the future!

Comment: Sorry, it is on a 10 minute timer. I will mark the question correct in 2 minutes.

Comment: I am also wondering if you can control the bouncy-ness of the effect. At the moment, the bounce is much too stiff.

Comment: Yes, try this: $(this).animate({ "top" : "+=100px" }, 400, { effect: "easeOutBounce", "times" : "2" });

Comment: the example in the answer works for me but the one in the comment above, does not.

Answer (score 0):

To Achieve a `bounce` easing effect with jQuery, you would need to **extend** the limited number of [available easing](http://per-property-easing) methods and add more advance ones. [Here's](http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/) a plugin for that which offer many cool easing functions.

You can also copy the easing method which you need (if you don't need the whole range of possibilities the plugin brings to the table) and incorporate it somewhere in your code:

```
/* jQuery easing */
jQuery.extend( jQuery.easing,{
    def: 'easeOutQuad',
    easeOutBounce: function (x,t,b,c,d) {
        if ((t/=d) < (1/2.75)) {
            return c*(7.5625*t*t) + b;
        } else if (t < (2/2.75)) {
            return c*(7.5625*(t-=(1.5/2.75))*t + .75) + b;
        } else if (t < (2.5/2.75)) {
            return c*(7.5625*(t-=(2.25/2.75))*t + .9375) + b;
        } else {
            return c*(7.5625*(t-=(2.625/2.75))*t + .984375) + b;
        }
    }
});
```

## Demo:

```js
function bounceDown(){
  $('.ball').animate({top:150}, 1000, 'easeOutBounce', onEnd);
}

function onEnd(){
  $(this).animate({top:0}, 500, 'easeOutCubic', bounceDown);
}

bounceDown();
```

```css
.ball{ 
  background:red; 
  border-radius:50%;
  display: inline-block;
  padding:30px;
  position:relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>

<div class='ball'></div>
```